# How to get the link of the page to which keycloak directs if clicked on "Forgot Password?"

Tags: keycloak

I am using keycloak for authentication. The login page I am using is not the one provided by keycloak. On this login page I have a "forgot password?" button. If the user clicks on this button, I want to direct the user to the page where they can fill in their username or email and get the password reset link on their email. For this, I need to know the URL of the page provided by keycloak where user fill in their username or email and get the email to reset their password.

Comment: https://HOSTNAME/auth/realms/REALM/login-actions/reset-credentials?client_id=CLIENT_ID    by this link, I think you can direct the user to keycloak forgot-password page. be aware of that it will be keycloak page.

Comment: @MuhammedYalçınKuru It should not have anything to do with the client's Id. On the login page when the user clicks on "forgot password?" I do not have anything except realm. And where can I find documentation of the APIs similar to the ....../login-actions/...?